# How to set a background image on an html file

Tags: css, background-image

I want to set a background image on an html file but it does not cover the entire length and width of the page and instead it goes up into a little box

I have tried using the `<body backround="">` but it still does not seem to help

```
body{
    font-family:'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: blanchedalmond;
}
body{
    background:
"https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.1f7d6c5c6cf7c6ee0a1c2168216394d2?rik=zTHGuOo31kdBNA&riu=http%3a%2f%2fgetwallpapers.com%2fwallpaper%2ffull%2fd%2fc%2fd%2f1241579-heavy-metal-wallpapers-hd-1920x1080-lockscreen.jpg&ehk=HWiLpk9ZFyCp%2bUhVMGRTxZ3d0IgkjYxJkoZcVTOMhSI%3d&risl=&pid=ImgRaw&r=0"
}
```

Comment: When you specify a background image in CSS, you need to wrap it in `url('')`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

Comment: The HTML `background` attribute has been obsolete for many, many years now. And, for terminologies sake, you want to set it on the HTML *element*, not the file.

Answer (score 0):

**1. background-size: cover; 

2. background-size: 100% 100%;**

```css
 body {
      background-image: url(anyImg);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```css
body{
     font-family:'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
     background-size: cover;
     background-color: blanchedalmond;
     background-image:url("https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.1f7d6c5c6cf7c6ee0a1c2168216394d2?rik=zTHGuOo31kdBNA&riu=http%3a%2f%2fgetwallpapers.com%2fwallpaper%2ffull%2fd%2fc%2fd%2f1241579-heavy-metal-wallpapers-hd-1920x1080-lockscreen.jpg&ehk=HWiLpk9ZFyCp%2bUhVMGRTxZ3d0IgkjYxJkoZcVTOMhSI%3d&risl=&pid=ImgRaw&r=0");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```